# How to resolve error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './sitemap_template.xml'

Tags: node.js, npm, enoent

I have a blog, and I want to transfer the local folders to another computer.

First, I `npm init` a new folder on my new computer. Then, I transfer all documents except 'node_modules' and 'public'.

Next, I run

```
npm install
npm install hexo-deployer-git --save
npm install hexo-generator-feed --save
npm install hexo-generator-sitemap --save
```

After hexo s, the terminal shows me text the following. How can I do to find my blog back? Thank you in advance.

```js
INFO  Validating config
INFO  Start processing
FATAL {
  err: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './sitemap_template.xml'
      at Object.openSync (fs.js:498:3)
      at readFileSync (fs.js:394:35)
      at module.exports (C:\Users\bbcco\myblog\node_modules\hexo-generator-sitemap\lib\template.js:27:34)
      at Hexo.module.exports (C:\Users\bbcco\myblog\node_modules\hexo-generator-sitemap\lib\generator.js:36:16)
      at Hexo.tryCatcher (C:\Users\bbcco\myblog\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
      at Hexo.<anonymous> (C:\Users\bbcco\myblog\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\method.js:15:34)
      at C:\Users\bbcco\myblog\node_modules\hexo\lib\hexo\index.js:405:22
      at tryCatcher (C:\Users\bbcco\myblog\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
      at MappingPromiseArray._promiseFulfilled (C:\Users\bbcco\myblog\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\map.js:68:38)
      at MappingPromiseArray.PromiseArray._iterate (C:\Users\bbcco\myblog\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise_array.js:115:31)
      at MappingPromiseArray.init (C:\Users\bbcco\myblog\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise_array.js:79:10)
      at MappingPromiseArray._asyncInit (C:\Users\bbcco\myblog\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\map.js:37:10)
      at _drainQueueStep (C:\Users\bbcco\myblog\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:97:12)
      at _drainQueue (C:\Users\bbcco\myblog\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:86:9)
      at Async._drainQueues (C:\Users\bbcco\myblog\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:102:5)
      at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (C:\Users\bbcco\myblog\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:15:14)
      at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:464:21) {
    errno: -4058,
    syscall: 'open',
    code: 'ENOENT',
    path: './sitemap_template.xml'
  }
} Something's wrong. Maybe you can find the solution here: %s https://hexo.io/docs/troubleshooting.html
```

Comment: Are you sure that there's a `sitemap_template.xml` in the current directory?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I have the `sitemap_template.xml` in my .deploy_git folder

Comment: It seems likely that one of these various processing tools is changing locations, so that the file that *was* `./sitemap_template.xml` is now, say, `../../sitemap_template.xml` or `/path/to/deploy/location/sitemap_template.xml` or some such.